# Remove Image from Grid

Tags: c#, image, grid

I am trying to remove an image from grid_main from grid_main using a counter that is going down each second, but the image is still staying there without the delete function. if the mole is clicked within the 3 seconds, then it will work, but if it is clicked after it is stuck there. Thanks!

Code:

```
MoleLifeCounter = 3;

// Create Grid \\
            Content_Grid.Children.Add(grid_Main);
            grid_Main.Height = MainWindowHeight;
            grid_Main.Width = MainWindowWidth;
            grid_Main.Background = Brushes.Transparent;

            // Grid Properties \\
            for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfColumns; i++)
            {
                ColumnDefinition newColumn = new ColumnDefinition();
                newColumn.Width = new GridLength(ColumnSize, GridUnitType.Pixel);
                grid_Main.ColumnDefinitions.Add(newColumn);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < NumberofRows; i++)
            {
                RowDefinition Row = new RowDefinition();
                Row.Height = new GridLength(RowSize, GridUnitType.Pixel);
                grid_Main.RowDefinitions.Add(Row);
            }

            // Fill Grid \\
            int RowCount = 0;
            int ColumnCount = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i <= NumofImages; i++)
            {
                Image newImage = HoleImage();
                if (RowCount < NumberofRows)
                {
                    if (ColumnCount < NumberOfColumns)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("ColumnCount: " + ColumnCount.ToString());
                        Grid.SetRow(newImage, RowCount);
                        Grid.SetColumn(newImage, ColumnCount);
                        grid_Main.Children.Add(newImage);
                        ColumnCount++;
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        RowCount++;
                        ColumnCount = 0;
                        Grid.SetRow(newImage, RowCount);
                        Grid.SetColumn(newImage, ColumnCount);
                        grid_Main.Children.Add(newImage);
                        ColumnCount++;
                        Console.WriteLine("RowCount: " + RowCount.ToString());
                    }
                }

                else
                {
                    break;
                }

                ChangeImage();
            }
        }

    private void deleteMole()
    {
        MoleLifeCounter = MoleLifeCounter--;

        if (MoleLifeCounter == 0)
        {
            grid_Main.Children.Remove(molePopup);
            MoleLifeCounter = 3;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where is deleteMole actually called? Showing us how you populate the Grid and the function that removes the mole doesn't give us too much information. The issue is probably with where you're calling deleteMole, but it could be something else related to updating the UI in the main thread. If you give us some more code to go on, I'd have a better idea of what's happening here. Thanks!

Comment: deleteMole() is called from a dispatcherTimer.